# incompatible SQL trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, hsqldb

Being newbie in SQL, can some help me adapt this trigger to either sqlite or HSQLDB, or maybe suggest a different approach?

I have this table in my db:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dfTree 
(
id INTEGER, 
parentId INTEGER,
name VARCHAR(20),
depth INTEGER,
lineage VARCHAR(100)
)
```

I try to set a trigger, but it seems incompatible with both db i tried (sqlite and HSQLDB)

```
CREATE TRIGGER dfTree_InsertTrigger ON dfTree
FOR INSERT AS
UPDATE child
    -- set the depth of this "child" to be the
    -- depth of the parent, plus one.
    SET depth = ISNULL(parent.depth + 1,0),
    -- the lineage is simply the lineage of the parent,
    -- plus the child's ID (and appropriate '/' characters
    lineage = ISNULL(parent.lineage,'/') + LTrim(Str(child.id)) + '/'
-- we can't update the "inserted" table directly,
-- so we find the corresponding child in the
-- "real" table
FROM dfTree child INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.id=child.id
-- now, we attempt to find the parent of this
-- "child" - but it might not exist, so these
-- values may well be NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN dfTree parent ON child.parentId=parent.id
```

(The trigger is supposed to calculate the "depth" and "lineage" fields upon new entry. I am following the article on Tree sturctures at http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4633/tree-structures-in-aspnet-and-sql-server/2/

Again, being newbie in SQL, can some help me adapt this trigger to either sqlite or HSQLDB, or maybe suggest a different approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dfTree_InsertTrigger 
after insert ON dfTree 
for each row
begin
  UPDATE dftree SET   
    depth = (select coalesce(depth + 1, 1) from (select depth from dftree parent where parent.id = new.parentid union all select null depth)),
    lineage = (select coalesce(lineage,'/') || dftree.id || '/' from (select lineage from dftree parent where parent.id = new.parentid union all select null lineage))
  where new.id = id;
end;
```

A couple of remarks:
- the operator for string concatenation in SQL is ||, not +
- coalesce() should be more portable than isnull
- the union all .. part ensures we always get a row (even if no parent exists)